# Overload the equals method in java

Tags: java, oop, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices regarding equals: to overload or not to overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910520/best-practices-regarding-equals-to-overload-or-not-to-overload)

Does anyone overload the equals method in java? The overloaded method will be

```
public boolean equals(final MyClass myClass)
```

This will have the benefit of having the relevant comparison part (guts of the method) in another method. Details are in my blog.

**EDIIT** : This is a genuine question. Link to the blog entry removed.

Comment: maybe a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910520/best-practices-regarding-equals-to-overload-or-not-to-overload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, it would be a bad idea because it would be liable to confuse someone reading your code.  I'd never do it.

If it becomes necessary to provide an "equality" method that does not override `boolean equals(Object)`, it is a much better idea to give it a *different* method name.