# In `equals(T value)`, must T be Object, or can it be like City, etc?

Tags: java, equals, referenceequals

I'm trying to understand the `equals()` method better. All examples I've seen do something like:

```
public class City
{
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (other instanceof City && other.getId().equals(this.id))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Must the method take on Object and not a City?

E.g. is this below not allowed?

```
public class City
{
    public boolean equals(City other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.id.equals(other.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it must be an `Object`. Else you're not **overriding** the *real* [`Object#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), but rather **overloading** it.

If you're only overloading it, then it *won't* be used by the standard API's like [Collection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html), etc.

#### Related questions:

- [Override or overload `equals()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910520/best-practices-regarding-equals-to-overload-or-not-to-overload)
- [How to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: And use `@Override` to make sure you haven't made a mistake.

Comment: Is that a problem? What effect does it have?

Comment: it has the effect that the equals method you think you wrote won't be used

Answer (score 1):

you can have both: (see poke's comment above)

```
public class City
{
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        return (other instanceof City) && equals((City)other) ;
    }
    public boolean equals(City other)
    {
        return other!=null && this.id.equals(other.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't take anything else than an `Object` if you want to override equals()!

Writing a specialized equals() method is a common error but tends to violate the equals() contract.

Comment: You can however do both, overloading it with a special `equals( City )` method, that is specialized in checking two cities, and then overriding the original `equals( Object )` method in which you will call `equals( City )` if the passed object is a City and do something else otherwise (like return false always).

Comment: @poke - +1 for great point! I find myself doing this quite often, on some rare occasions it has had a positive performance impact.

Comment: Of course you two are right. What I meant is that this often leads to error prone code. As long as you know what you are doing and use the override annotation properly, there is no big deal.