# What is the difference between java.util.Objects.equals and com.google.common.base.Objects.equals?

Tags: java, guava

Is there any reason to use the Guava one istead of the java.util implementation?

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038204/apache-commons-equals-hashcode-builder

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`java.util.Objects` and its `equals` method only exist since Java 7. The Guava version predates it. If you are using at least Java 7, there's no reason to use the Guava version.

Comment: The javadocs on Guava's Objects.equal() method say: Note for Java 7 and later: This method should be treated as deprecated; use Objects.equals(Object, Object) instead.

Answer (score 7):

One difference besides the fact that the Guava method predates the Java 7 one: the Guava method is called *`equal`* while the Java method is called `equals`. This is actually significant because it means the Java version can't be used with a static import. (Even ignoring that, I think `equal` is a better name for a static method that takes two arguments and compares them for equality, while `equals` is better for an instance method like `Object.equals`.)

All that said, if you're on JDK7 you should probably use the `java.util.Objects` version.