# Removed duplicate element from List

Tags: java, list

I have this list which is collection of GrossBalanceDtlsVO class.

GrossBalanceDtlsVO class contains below field :

```
private Long customerID = null;

private BigDecimal instAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

private BigDecimal instBalanceAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

private BigDecimal instRedemptionAmt = BigDecimal.ZERO; 

private Long instTxnCnt = null;

private Date monthEndDt = null;
....
....



List<GrossBalanceDtlsVO> grossDetailsVO2 = getPCCustomerDetails(customerID);
```

This list contains duplicate data. For example :

```
customerID=1000033195, monthEndDt=2016-05-31, recMonthNo=9, recMonthlyLimit=100, recBalanceAmt=100, recMonthlyRedemption=0, recRollOverEligibility=0, txnId=null, instTxnCnt=null, instAmount=0, instBalanceAmount=0, instRedemptionAmt=0]
customerID=1000033195, monthEndDt=2016-06-30, recMonthNo=10, recMonthlyLimit=100, recBalanceAmt=100, recMonthlyRedemption=0, recRollOverEligibility=0, txnId=null, instTxnCnt=null, instAmount=0, instBalanceAmount=0, instRedemptionAmt=0]
customerID=1000033195, monthEndDt=2016-07-31, recMonthNo=11, recMonthlyLimit=100, recBalanceAmt=100, recMonthlyRedemption=0, recRollOverEligibility=0, txnId=null, instTxnCnt=null, instAmount=0, instBalanceAmount=0, instRedemptionAmt=0]
customerID=1000033195, monthEndDt=2016-05-31, recMonthNo=9, recMonthlyLimit=100, recBalanceAmt=100, recMonthlyRedemption=0, recRollOverEligibility=0, txnId=null, instTxnCnt=null, instAmount=0, instBalanceAmount=0, instRedemptionAmt=0]
customerID=1000033195, monthEndDt=2016-06-30, recMonthNo=10, recMonthlyLimit=100, recBalanceAmt=100, recMonthlyRedemption=0, recRollOverEligibility=0, txnId=null, instTxnCnt=null, instAmount=0, instBalanceAmount=0, instRedemptionAmt=0]
customerID=1000033195, monthEndDt=2016-07-31, recMonthNo=11, recMonthlyLimit=100, recBalanceAmt=100, recMonthlyRedemption=0, recRollOverEligibility=0, txnId=null, instTxnCnt=null, instAmount=0, instBalanceAmount=0, instRedemptionAmt=0]
```

Now my question is that how to remove those duplicate data from this list?

Comment: Do your objects have `equals` and `hashcode` methods? Do you need to preserve original order?

Comment: Is customer id the unique identifier? If yes how are other parameters different with same cust id?

Comment: iterate, create the unique key from the object, put in a hashmap and when done use the hashmap values?

Comment: redefine equal an hashcode methods in GrossBalanceDtlsVO and use Set List to remove duplication.

Comment: I don't have the equals and hashcode. Even how can I use those methods to remove duplicate? order is not necessity @tamasrev

Comment: @Shiladittya Chakraborty covert your list into set and set autometically removes duplicate elements

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty it will help you i recentely tried with custom object.

Comment: If you have good `equals()` and `hashcode()` then you can filter duplicates with a `HashSet`. Anyway, you need to determine whether these `GrossBalanceDtlsVO ` equal. Then, why not add an `equals` method?

Answer (score 1):

Sort them by given criteria, iterate them and check if the previous element is equal to the current element, if true - push them in separate list/array, and after that iterate this list/array and remove the items from your list.

Note: you should write your own object comparator.

For future use, if you want to have distinct collection - use a set.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw your list into a Set and this Set into a new List.

```
List<GrossBalanceDtlsVO> grossDetailsVO2 = getPCCustomerDetails(customerID);
Set<GrossBalanceDtlsVO> grossDetailsVO2Set = new HashSet<>(grossDetailsVO2);
List<GrossBalanceDtlsVO> grossDetailsVO2WithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(grossDetailsVO2Set);
```

Comment: This way does only work if you have equals() and hashCode() implemented. So you should implement those two methods (perhaps using `EqualsBuilder` and `HashCodeBuilder` or with Guavas `Objects` as stated in the answer to [this SO-question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038204/apache-commons-equals-hashcode-builder))

Comment: keep in mind that using a set would mean you lose order.