# Does the equals method work with objects? If so, how?

Tags: java, object, comparison, object-comparison

I have a program that is zoo and in the zoo there are branched subgroups of animals that are reptiles.  When I do an equals method the main program compiles and it runs. I'm confused how does java know to use the equals method if I'm comparing objects and not specifically int or String?

```
public class Zoo {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Animal a=new Animal("Bob");
        Reptile komodo= new Reptile("Snakey");
        komodo.bask();
        a.size=3;
        komodo.size=5;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(komodo);
        Turtle t= new Turtle("Slowy");
        t.hide();
        t.size=6;
        t.numlegs=4;
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println(t.equals(komodo));
    }
}

public class Animal {
    public String name;

    public boolean equals(Animal other) {
        return other.size==this.size;
    }

    public Animal(String s) {
        name=s;
    }
    public void setName(String n) {
        this.name=n;
    }
    public void eat(String meal) {
        System.out.println("chump chump yummy "+meal);
    }
    public int size;

    public String toString() {
        return "I am "+name+" and I'm "+size+" cm long";
    }

}

public class Reptile extends Animal {

    public Reptile(String n) {
        super(n);
        numlegs=0;
    }
    public Reptile(String n, int l) {
        super(n);
        numlegs=l;
    }

    public void bask() {
        System.out.println("basking...");
    }
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+numlegs+" legs";
    }

    public int numlegs;
}
public class Turtle extends Reptile {

    public Turtle(String n) {
        super (n,4);
        shellColor="Brown";
    }
    public void hide() {
        System.out.println("you cant see me");
    }
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+" and my shell is"+ shellColor;
    }
    public String shellColor;

    public void bask() {
        super.bask();
        System.out.println("turtle is basking...");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

You're not overriding the `Object#equals` method, but overloading it. In your method declaration you use `Animal` type instead of `Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Animal other)
```

A good overriding of the method would be using the `instanceof` operator. Showing an example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if(other instanceof Animal) {
        Animal otherAnimal = (Animal)other;
        //comparison logic...
    }
    return false;
}
```

More info on the subject:

- [Best practices regarding equals: to overload or not to overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2910520/1065197)
- [Overriding Object.equals VS Overloading it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12787947/1065197)

Answer (score 2):

For your question on how java knows how to compare objects,
you need to override the equals method

```
 public boolean equals(Object other){
    // return true or false based on your logic

  }
```

While comparing, equals method is used.
You can have a look at this good tutorial which explains the significance of the equals method.

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/26/what-is-the-significance-of-equals-method-in-java/

Also, only overriding equals is not enough if you are using objects into collections those use hashing. You will find a good tutorial at

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/28/significance-of-equals-and-hashcode/

Comment: Object do not have member size.

Comment: +1 for mentioning overridding hashing, i'd say though that the hash should always be overridden if the equals is overridden otherwise the contract is broken. A good IDE will generate the new hash for you

Comment: @RichardTingle yes sir I have mentioned all those points in the tutorial I've provided. It will help me improve if you have a look at it and provide feedback also. That will be really appreciated

Comment: @RichardTingle the IDE would only call `super.hashCode()` so no matter how good the IDE is, the auto generated implementation of `hashCode` is not right =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza My IDE (netbeans) allows you to click the warning message about not overriding the hashcode and select "generate hash code", you then select the fields you want to use for your hash and it autogenerates it

Answer (score 0):

Every class inherits the `Object` class silently. And the `Object` class has a `equals` method. So if any class doesn't override the equals method then it will use the default implementation of `Object.equals.`

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

From the source code of Object.equals

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

So If any object doesn't have it's own implementation of equals then the `equals` method will simply check if the object reference is same or not.

So get a desired result from equals you need to implement by your own as alread suggested in other answer